# How to create a Word VBA equation using oMaths that formats exponents and fractions?

Tags: excel, vba, math, ms-word

I am using Excel VBA to write equations in Word.

The fraction component of the equation is not formatting correctly. The expression has a fraction where both numerator and denominator have an exponent. I can't get the exponents in the correct position.

I attempted to use brackets and extra spaces - resulting in either no buildup of the equation object, or strange exponents.

```
Sub TextToEquation()
Dim appWord as Word.Application
Dim eqText as String
Dim ac as OMathAutoCorrectEntry
Dim eqObj as Word.OMaths

'Create new word application
Set appWord = New Word.Application

With appWord
   'Create new word document
   .Documents.Add
   'Turn Math Autocorrect On
   .OMathAutoCorrect.UseOutsideOMath = True

   With .Selection
      'Write Text
      .Text = "x^2 \times x^5/x^3"

      'Find any math autocorrect and replace with character
      For each ac in appWord.OMathAutoCorrect.Entries
         If InStr(.text, ac.Name) > 0 then
            .text = Replace(.text, ac.name, ac.value)
         End If
      Next ac
   End With

   'Add math object
   Set eqObj = .OMaths.Add(.Range).OMaths.item(1)
   'Build up equation <<< THIS IS WHERE THE BUG LIES
   eqObj.BuildUp
   eqObj.BuildUp

End With
```

Note: Actual code is different, but this is the relevant code snippet modified to work independently.

Comment: Is [THIS](https://prnt.sc/qoddzj) what you are trying to achieve? If yes, then **1.** 
 `Dim eqObj as Word.OMaths` should be `Dim eqObj as Word.OMath` **2.** `Set eqObj = .OMaths.Add(.Range).OMaths.item(1)` should be inside the `With .Selection... End With` block. One tip: Avoid working with `Selection`. Work with a range object. Much easier to handle the code. **3.** You have an extra `eqObj.BuildUp`

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, but I am still unable to make the exponent work out. It ends up with two powers on top of the fraction and none on bottom.

Comment: I had kept the code ready for you but discarded it since you did nto reply back :D I am stepping out for sometime. will try and post an answer in the evening when i come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I haven't been able to work out why the original code doesn't work, but by working backwards I found a solution. Note that this is situational code, so it isn't the most direct code.

```
Sub runTest()
    Dim appWord As Word.Application

    Set appWord = New Word.Application

    With appWord
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add
        For i = 1 To 5
            .Selection.TypeText "\equation{x^" & i & " \times x^5/x^3}"
            .Selection.TypeParagraph
            .Selection.TypeParagraph
        Next i
    End With

    Call TextToEquation(appWord)


End Sub

Sub TextToEquation(appWord As Word.Application)
    Dim objRange As Word.Range
    Dim objEq As Word.OMath
    Dim objText As String

    With appWord
        With .Selection

            'Search the document for \equation{} tags
            With .Find
                'Search Settings
                .ClearFormatting
                .Format = False
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                'Search Text
                .text = "\\equation\{*\}"
                .Replacement.text = ""
                .MatchWildcards = True
                'Execute search
                .Execute
            End With 'Find

            Do 'While there are still \equation{} tags to be found
                'Select location to insert equation
                Set objRange = .Range

                'Write equation text
                objText = objRange.text
                objText = Replace(Replace(objText, "\equation{", ""), "}", "")  'Remove tag
                objText = MathSymbol(objText)                                   'Replace math symbols

                'Create equation
                objRange.text = objText
                Set objRange = .OMaths.Add(objRange)
                Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
                objEq.BuildUp

                'Search for the next occurrence
                .Find.Execute

            Loop While .Find.Found
        End With 'Selection
    End With 'appWord

End Sub

Function MathSymbol(strText As String) As String

    strText = Replace(strText, "\times", Chr(215))  'Multiplication symbol

    MathSymbol = strText

End Function
```